# Python Join Two Dataframe by Groupby on opposite sorting order on two column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two dataframes that I would like to calculate difference between two columns using groupby, so for df1 groupby ColA & ColB and sort ColD assending, join df2 with groupby ColA2 & ColB2 and sort ColD dessending, and match join df2 to df1 with df2's ColD2 information. Thank you in advance.

df 1

```
  colA   ColB    ColD
     A    3H1     150
     A    3H1     550   
     A    HYT     250
     B    3H1     350
     B    3H1     450
     B    8YT     750
     C    8YT    1050
     C    8YT     450
     C    3H1     250
     C    8YT     550
     C    8YT     750
     C    3H1     650
```

df 2

```
  colA2  ColB2   ColD2   ColC2
     A    3H1     500      A50
     A    3H1     600      B50
     A    HYT     300      G60
     B    3H1     500      T67
     B    3H1    1500      H63
     B    8YT     800      K72
     C    8YT     700      Y23
     C    8YT     400      O98
     C    3H1     200      Y11
     C    8YT     500      A78
     C    8YT     700      H23
```

output: basically keep the df1 dataframe and have df2 join in with groupby ColA and ColB, sort ColD2 revesial to ColD's sort (ColD assending, ColD2 dessending), and have df2's ColC2 joinin as well.

```
  colA   ColB    ColD    ColD2    ColC2
     A    3H1     150     600      B50
     A    3H1     550     500      A50
     A    HYT     250     300      G60
     B    3H1     350    1500      H63
     B    3H1     450     500      T67
     B    8YT     750     800      K72
     C    8YT     450     700      H23
     C    8YT     550     700      Y23
     C    3H1     250     200      Y11
     C    8YT     750     500      A78
     C    8YT    1050     400      O98
     C    3H1     650     na       na
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df2 = df2.sort_values(by=["colA2", "ColB2", "ColD2"], ascending=[True, True, False])

df1["tmp"] = df1.groupby(["colA", "ColB"]).cumcount().values
df2["tmp"] = df2.groupby(["colA2", "ColB2"]).cumcount().values

x = df1.merge(
    df2, left_on=["colA", "ColB", "tmp"], right_on=["colA2", "ColB2", "tmp"], how="left"
)
print(x[["colA", "ColB", "ColD", "ColD2", "ColC2"]])
```

Prints:

```
   colA ColB  ColD   ColD2 ColC2
0     A  3H1   150   600.0   B50
1     A  3H1   550   500.0   A50
2     A  HYT   250   300.0   G60
3     B  3H1   350  1500.0   H63
4     B  3H1   450   500.0   T67
5     B  8YT   750   800.0   K72
6     C  8YT  1050   700.0   Y23
7     C  8YT   450   700.0   H23
8     C  3H1   250   200.0   Y11
9     C  8YT   550   500.0   A78
10    C  8YT   750   400.0   O98
11    C  3H1   650     NaN   NaN
```